# How can I prevent a production flutter app from running in emulators?

Tags: flutter, production-environment

I have no idea how to block or prevent my production application from running on emulators or softwares such as BlueStacks

Does anyone come up with a solution for this problem?

Comment: You'd need something an emulator or VM couldn't reliably replicate, and there's a very short list of things like that. The speed of hardware is the only thing that comes to mind, but it'd give you loads of false positives in a mobile app.

Comment: @Marcos If you look at how the flutter team checks for that here https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/7b8203af33e214666c3f0809789ae1c7d4c83ae8/packages/device_info/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/deviceinfo/DeviceInfoPlugin.java#L105 you can see that there isn't really a catch all solution. It will just catch known emulators. Technically anymore could create a new one with different product names and your app would run on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use package https://pub.dev/packages/device_info

add dependency in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  device_info: ^0.4.0+3
```

and here is example how to detect is it real device or not

```
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Is am i in matrix?')),
        body: Test(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _isRealDevice(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(child: Text('is it real device: ${snapshot.data}'));
        } else {
          return const SizedBox.shrink();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _isRealDevice() async {
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
    return androidInfo.isPhysicalDevice;
  }
}
```

I don't have installed Genymotion but on AS emulators it shows `false` as intended.

Comment: Thanks, currently this is the most helpful answer